# why not all tables are displayed in SQuirrel-SQL

Tags: oracle, squirrel-sql

Using Oracle DB 10 and SQuirrel 3.7.1

Not all tables are displayed in 'Objects-tab -> schemeName -> table' list.

If I write in the SQL tab `select * from tableName` I get a result, but the table is not displayed on the list above.

How can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

`tableName` might not be a **table**. It can be e.g. a view, synonym, materialized view so it would then be displayed under its node (i.e. not for "tables" but for "views" etc.).